# Open SSL programming in C

Tags: c, ssl, cryptography, websocket, openssl

I am trying to write a program in C, where a  HTTPS client which connects to a remote SSL server, sends an encrypted HTTP request and prints out the server's response (the web page).

I was experimenting to run [some examples from here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/sockets/programs/)

Especially the [test-port-client.c](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/sockets/programs/part1/chap2/test-port-client.c)

but it is not showing the result that I am expecting.

I checked whether I have openssl in my laptop, by the following command

```
apt-cache search libssl | grep SSL
```

and the result I got is as follows.

```
libssl-dev - SSL development libraries, header files and documentation
libssl-doc - SSL development documentation documentation
libssl1.0.0 - SSL shared libraries
libssl-ocaml - OCaml bindings for OpenSSL (runtime)
libssl-ocaml-dev - OCaml bindings for OpenSSL
libssl0.9.8 - SSL shared libraries
libsslcommon2 - enterprise messaging system - common SSL libraries
libsslcommon2-dev - enterprise messaging system - common SSL development files
```

I am compiling the program in C as follows :

```
gcc test-port-client.c -o test-port-client
```

and then run it as follows:

```
./test-port-client google.com 80 abc
```

But I dont know, how to tweak the code for my requirement.

### My requirement is something like

> "HTTPS client which connects to a remote SSL server, sends an encrypted HTTP request and >prints out the server's response (the web page). In addition, your program verifies that >the X.509 certificate provided by the server is valid and chains to a root certificate you >trust."

Any guidance will be much appreciated. Help me please.

Comment: Check this example http://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/sockets/programs/part4/chap16/ssl_client.c

Comment: @Sergey  How to compile and run that file. I am using ubuntu 13.0

and the [error is ](http://shrib.com/error2)

Comment: Your question is worthless here and liable to deletion unless the code is posted here.

Comment: I am not trying to build something by my own, just trying to use the program available online and I am providing links to the code @EJP

Comment: @user2888239 You should add libraries to link  "gcc ssl-cleint1.c -lcrypt -lopenssl -o ssl-cleint1"

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat confused. The code that you're trying to run has nothing to do with SSL. It just looks like a simple TCP packet sender. What are you seeing, and what are you expecting to see?

For a quick ramp up to network programming, take a look at Beej's guide: 
http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/

And for OpenSSL, this might be a good starting point:
http://savetheions.com/2010/01/16/quickly-using-openssl-in-c/

Though, the above example doesn't do certificate validation. But it would be a good test to validate your library install, and that you can compile against the appropriate libraries.

Comment: I am looking for some output like this



<code> $ ./ssl www.pcwebshop.co.uk 443
Certificate OK: no
Problem: self signed certificate
Certificate subject:
- Common name: Parallels Panel
- Organization name: Parallels
- Organizational unit: Parallels Panel
Certificate issuer:
- Common name: Parallels Panel
- Organization name: Parallels
- Organizational unit: Parallels Panel
===
Exiting due to error: self signed certificate

Comment: I am getting the following [error](http://shrib.com/ssl-erros) when I run  http://savetheions.com/2010/01/16/quickly-using-openssl-in-c/

Comment: So, that error means that it can't find the libraries that were linked at compile time. Where is openssl installed on your machine, and is it  that in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH? You can also try compiling static (-static on the build line).